# pgfplots move colorbar scaled label to top right

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

Hi I was wondering how to shift the scaled label on the colorbar to the top right? The has been autogenerated by `matlab2tikz`, but I would like to move the .10^-3 to the top right like it was originially in matlab.

[image: imagesc example]

I figured it would be something with `colorbar style ={y tick label...` but I couldnt find the correct option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label with " .10^-3" is called "tick scale label" and the associated style can be modified using `colorbar style={y tick scale label style={...}}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,colorbar style={y tick scale label style={xshift=0.5cm}}]
\addplot[mesh,ultra thick] {20000*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

In order to align the tick scale label in the same way as tick labels, you can use

```
y tick scale label style={
    at={(yticklabel* cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length})},
    yshift=7pt,
    anchor=near yticklabel,
},
```

instead of the absolute shift value. This will place it exactly as the tick labels. The point  `(yticklabel* cs:1)` is always the uppermost point on the axis, and `:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}` shifts it by the default amount just as tick labels.

Comment: Thank you so much! Does this mean I would have to tweak it each time i changed the figure size? If so is there a way to set to align with the y tick labels on the colourbar?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a suggestion how to get that alignment.